# фильтр ломает вёрстку слайдера slick.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slick.js, filter

Сделал слайдер на `slick.js`

Пытаюсь сделать фильтр,но он ломает вёрстку

код фильтра:

```
$("#cat1-cb").change(function() {
  if ($("#cat1-cb").is(":checked")) {
    $(".category1").show();
  } else {
    $(".category1").hide();
  }
});
$("#cat2-cb").change(function() {
  if ($("#cat2-cb").is(":checked")) {
    $(".category2").show();
  } else {
    $(".category2").hide();
  }
});
$("#cat3-cb").change(function() {
  if ($("#cat3-cb").is(":checked")) {
    $(".category3").show();
  } else {
    $(".category3").hide();
  }
});
```

Как сделать что бы фильтр сдвигал элементы при сокрытии ?
полный код: https://jsfiddle.net/cf353shk/9/

Answer (score 0):

чтобы скрипт не ломал вёрстку можно сделать фиксированную высоту блока .slick-track. Для этого в таблицу стилей добавьте следующее:

```css
.slick-track {
    height: 100px; /* 100 заменить на подходящее значение */
}
```

Чтобы фильтр сдвигал элементы, необходимо использовать другой, так как данный скрипт группирует все элементы по 2.

Comment: Извините,а не могли бы пример показать ?
я только начинаю разбираться с javascript и фронтендом в целом